# Get label from PT Pill field

Tags: pixelandtonic, tags, field-pack

I have a FieldPack Pill field called `companies_type` with the following options:

```
physical : Physical Store
webshop : Webshop
```

To print the fields value I can just use `companies_type` but how can I get the value's label? (Webshop or Physical Store in the this situation)

I've tried with `companies_type:label`, `companies_type:option`, `companies_type:value` and all those inside a tag pair as wel: `{companies_type}{label}{/companies_type}`

Anyone know how/if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one correct syntax style: `{companies_type:label}`.

If it's not working you might have changed your options after saving an entry. So the stored value is not matching any options anymore and thus resulting an empty value for `{companies_type:label}` and `{companies_type}`.